# Phonegap-Jquery compatibility issue in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, single-page-application

I am working on a phonegap project that has sliding panel which closes after pressing any button in that panel and also loads data.

I have made it working on my Nexus 4 but the main problem occurred when I checked on LG Optimus G Pro the slider does not closes itself after click it has to be closed explicitly. The strange thing is same problem occurred on all the Samsung device.

Following is the code for the slider

```
    <script>
                $(document).on("pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {
                    $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function(e) {
                        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
                        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
                        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
                        if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
                            if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
                                $("#dvAppSideMenu").panel("open");
                            } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
                                $("#left-panel").panel("open");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">

            <div id="dvPageButton" class="pageHeaderMenu shadowSmall">

                <div class="scrollArea">
                    <a id="aWall_Main" data-action="home" class="mainWall">
                        <div data-target="1">
                            Home
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#maincontent" data-target="1" data-subtarget="0" data-section="secDataZero" class="dont shadowInset" data-rel="close">ABC</a>
                    <a href="#maincontent" data-target="1" data-subtarget="1" data-section="secDataOne" class="dont shadowInset" data-rel="close">PQR</a>
                    <a href="#maincontent" data-target="1" data-subtarget="2" data-section="secDataTwo" class="dont shadowInset" data-rel="close">XYZ</a>
                    <a class="dont shadowInset setting-btn" href="#" >Setting</a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="theme-button">
                <a class="th-btn1" href="#" data-rel="close"><span>Theme A</span></a>
                <a class="th-btn2" href="#" data-rel="close"><span>Theme B</span></a>
                <a class="th-btn3" href="#" data-rel="close"><span>Theme C</span></a>
                <a class="th-btn4" href="#" data-rel="close"><span>Theme D</span></a>
                <a class="th-btn5" href="#" data-rel="close"><span>Theme E</span></a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Note: This being phonegap app may not work on browser.

Do anyone have idea why is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the [Alpha 2](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/08/15/jquery-mobile-1-4-0-alpha-2-released/#download) version of jQuery Mobile 1.4. They have done (and are doing) lots of work on the panel in this version.